# BigQuery: How to convert Year to Decade?

Tags: google-bigquery

In this great [`article`](https://tilwbq.com/investigating-global-temperature-trends-with-bigquery-and-tableau-46c6ddd036ba), I found the way to convert Year into Decade, but it looks too verbose to me!

Is there better way to do this?

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT '1921' AS YEAR UNION ALL
  SELECT '1932' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1943' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1954' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1985' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2006' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018' 
)
SELECT
  YEAR,
  CASE 
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "192%" THEN "20S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "193%" THEN "30S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "194%" THEN "40S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "195%" THEN "50S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "196%" THEN "60S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "197%" THEN "70S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "198%" THEN "80S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "199%" THEN "90S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "200%" THEN "2000S"
    WHEN YEAR LIKE "201%" THEN "2010S"
  END AS DECADES
FROM data
-- ORDER BY YEAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "extract" Decade from Year - [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace) function can be used as in example below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT '1921' AS YEAR UNION ALL
  SELECT '1932' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1943' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1954' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1985' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2006' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2028' 
)
SELECT
  YEAR,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(YEAR, r'(?:19)(\d)\d|(20\d)\d', '\\1\\20s') AS DECADES
FROM data
-- ORDER BY YEAR
```

Comment: Why not use `TRUNC` after casting to `INT64`?

Comment: sure, why not? that's an option. but when i "evaluated" it before answering - i got impression that it is still a little wordy to get exactly same result as in article - it can be matter of preferences though :o)